# How should crane remote control diagram be connected?

Tags: remote-control, diagram

could someone please explain diagram for the crane remote control.

What does it means power1 and power2 and drawn coil? What does coil represents?

Also there should be control for up and down (some kind of relay) but in the diagram they are all connected.

If anyone can make sense out of this please help out.

It was from the document: https://fccid.io/JI9-F21-2S-033/User-Manual/User-Manual-1755896.pdf

[image]

Comment: Questions on the use of electric devices are off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That drawing appears to just show the external connections to the radio control reciever. The coil represent the primary of the power transformer.

The Power 1, Power 2 terminals and coil represent the power input to the receiver.  The rest of the drawing represents the relay contacts - in an electrical drawing, the parallel vertical lines are a common representation of a normally-open relay contact.

Comment: If I understand you, power1 and power2 would be regular socket supply? And what would be MAIN and COM, don't they also mean regular socket COM and MAIN?

Comment: So if I would connect 110VAC to Power1 and 2 ... and I would control motor which is 110VAC, in that case I would also connect COM and MAIN to 110VAC?

Comment: How you connect this controller to your existing crane controls will depend on how the crane controls are wired.  If you need assistance makeing these connections, you should discuss things with your equipment suppliers.

Answer (score 0):

It represents line and neutral in a standard AC circuit. The coil is probably the primary side of a transformer to reduce the voltage to something used in the control system, either 12 or 24 volts.